# PHP Memory Limit Reverting to 2M twice a day

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, lamp, bitnami

recently migrated from a cPanel managed server to GCP compute engine running bitnami-lampstack-7-3-17-1-linux-debian-9-x86-64.

The error below did not occur in the previous cPanel environment.

I changed the memory_limit to 64M in /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini and changed and I added the php_value[memory_limit]=64M to the /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php-fpm.conf file and twice a day, late afternoon and very early morning, the site would throw the out of memory error with 2M as the memory limit until I restart php-fpm  I even added ini_set('memory_limit', '128M) to a init.php file that is included on every page and it still reverts back to 2M and throws the error around the same time each day until I restart php-fpm

.htaccess is disabpled in Apache httpd.conf:

    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied

I don't have any crons running and I have not been able to identify any patterns in the php error log that would create more insight.

Thank you for any help and insight

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here.

One of the reasons of that is the amount of requests your server is receiving. If a bot or attacker is requesting your site many times, you need to increase the memory your site uses. You can take a look at the access_log file (/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ folder) to see if there is a specific IP that is requesting your site many times. A useful command would be this one

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/
tail -n 10000 access_log | awk '{print $1}'| sort| uniq -c| sort -nr| head -n 10
```

You can later modify the httpd-app.conf file of your custom application or the main virtual host (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf) to deny the connections to that IP

```
deny from 1.2.3.4
```

You will need to restart Apache later

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You can find more information here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/lamp/troubleshooting/deny-connections-bots/

Comment: thank you for the reply.  Many times we are on the site in the afternoon when the memory limit reverts back to 2M and we log the exact time.  I reviewed just prior to the memory limit reverting to 2M and I don't see an increase in unusual activity/requests.  I saw a couple 408 responses, but that was all that looked strange.  The limit reverts to 2M in the slowest parts of our day as well.

Comment: There should be something configured in the machine that it's changing the configuration and restarting the services. Please note that the memory_limit value is something that needs to be changed in the configuration files and the services need to be restarted for the changes to take effect